# Fetching data from json file, using python3. How to printspesific parts from datapool?

Tags: json, python-3.x

So Ive been trying to get data from this json file containing stock info. Im completely new to python, and json is almost foreign. But I do understand the concepts, and I could need a little push in the right direction. Ive been doing beginners guides on python, and have spent lots of time to figure this out on my own, and honestly I dont know what Im doing, and I recon I should do more study, but Im really hung up on this.
So forgive me for asking questions, when Im probably not even going to understand any answers you might suggest. But then I can atleast do more research based on your suggestions, and gain more knowledge, do some testing and get it down.

Im on archlinux, with python 3, i have the code in some.py files which i run in the terminal. Ive been googeling and done lots of testing. I see there are several ways to do what im trying to do, and I also got some other samples to work, where the json file was structured a bit differently. But I could never get it working on the json file ive been trying to get data from. Below is what ive got.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

    import urllib.request
    import json
    url = 'https://silverrive.com/pages/Issuers_sample.json'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)

    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    cont = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))

    print(cont)
```

So if you look at the json file the are different entries, and I would like to be able to extract for example only the strings/numbers which contains "ShortingPercent", and have them printet in my terminal. Now Ive not been getting any errors with the code presentet above, the problem is the entire contents of json file gets dumped into my terminal, So I guess Im on the right track by actually getting the data to the terminal, but I dont know how to sort it, exclude or just fetch the parts I need.

All the tesing Ive done to just print parts of the data always results in "undefined" string, or that the indice list must be integers and not strings or something like that. So I kinda know what the problem is,I just dont know how the correct syntax should look like. I do believe it has something to do with format strings, but Ive not been able to produce anything more then explained above.

Also I know I should be learning more basics before strying stuff like this, but It facinated me, and yes i have ocd, so is really bugging me.

Ive hosted the json file on my own website, so you can copypaste the code and see all the json data coming in.

If any one wants to help out, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The entire json file is loaded into cont.You just need to filter the required values.

Comment: print(cont['Positions'][0]['ShortPercent'])
   print(cont['Positions'][1]['ShortPercent'])

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried some variations based on your suggestions, but Ive not been able to actualy pull data out off "cont", I tried adding the following, just to see if i could get some output.


print(cont['ShortPercent']) # or 
print(cont['NetShortPosition']['Id'])
print(cont['NetShortPosition']['2'])
print(cont['Positions'][0]['ShortPercent'])
print(cont['Positions'][1]['ShortPercent'])
print(cont['ISIN'][3]['ShortPercent'])

So the "cont" gets fets filled with all the jason data, but Im not able to sort the values. I must be missunderstanding something. @shovan rai

Comment: Wow, that got messy sorry about that. Here is some of the output from terminal:


>>> print(cont['Positions'][1]['ShortPercent'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>> print(cont['ISIN'][3]['ShortPercent'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>>

Comment: Sorry about that, You need to index the cont variable first.I have added a screenshot, please refer to it.

Comment: Yes! thats is, got it working now, thank you @shovan_rai ! Much appreciated

Comment: I think I did so, also added rep, can you confirm? And how do I mark the thread as "Solved"?